# I need to extract an element from a tag using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, tags, gettext

Simply put, I have the below tag in my soup and I need to extract the date from the `'value'` element.

```
<input class="mm-date-field form-control input-sm date-picker" title="Select as of date" type="text" value="03/31/2023"/>
```

I've tried a number of things after searching online, but my latest attempts were the below:

```
date = cmbs_soup.find('input', title = 'Select as of date', type = 'text', value = re.compile('.*'))
date.text

date = cmbs_soup.find('input', {"class": "mm-date-field form-control input-sm date-picker", "title": "Select as of date", "type": "text"}).get_text("value")
print(date)
```

Both resulted in `''` - an **empty string**. What am I missing?!?!

Ty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get any [tag attribute](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#bs4.Tag.attrs) by treating it like a dictionary - with [`<Tag>.get(<attr>)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/get) [if you're not sure the element will have that attribute] or `<Tag>[<attr>]` [if you *are* sure that the element has that key].

If you find the element with

```
date = cmbs_soup.find('input', title='Select as of date', type='text', value=True) # OR
# date = cmbs_soup.select_one('input.mm-date-field.form-control.input-sm.date-picker[title="Select as of date"][type="text"][value]')
```

then you can get the `value` attribute with `date['value']` or `date.get('value')` or `date.attrs['value']` or `date.attrs.get('value')`.

Comment: Amazing! I was thinking about this all wrong. Thank you!